# spring bean - inject Context Base URL in property

Tags: spring-mvc, javabeans

On Spring 3, I got a bean in my applicationContext.xml with this definition :

```
<bean id="serviceProperties" class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">
    <property name="service" value="http://www.mysite.com/my_webapp/j_spring_cas_security_check"/>
    <property name="sendRenew" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

Instead of

```
"value="http://www.mysite.com/my_webapp/j_spring_cas_security_check"
```

Is there a way to directly and dynamically inject the "base URL" of my tomcat server + j_spring_cas_security_check

( like we can do in a jsp to set  :

```
  <base href="<%=request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName()+ ":" +  request.getServerPort() + request.getContextPath()+ "/"%>" />
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<spring:url value="/j_spring_cas_security_check" var="baseUrl" />
<base href="${baseUrl}" />
```

spring:url evaluates the URL "/j_spring_cas_security_check" relative to your application path and stores it in baseUrl variable.  After this, you can replace ${baseUrl} in your JSP.

It's recommended not to use base tag.  Instead, you should have relative paths but this is up to you.

Hope it helps.